# How to get rid of 5* artifacts besides leveling up other artifacts?

Tags: genshin-impact

I'm constantly at the limit of 1500 artifacts and about 1/3rd of them are 5-star artifacts.

When at the limit, I go to my inventory and destroy some 4* artifacts or lvl up some 5*, just to free up some artifact space.
But I also want to remove some 5* artifacts that got bad stats without leveling another one up, as that's very time consuming.

Is there any easy way to get rid of 5* artifacts other than levelung up other artifacts, just like destroying 4* artifacts?

[image: Picture of "This item cannot be destroyed" with a 5* artifact]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you reach Adventurer Rank level 45, you unlock the Mystic Offering at an Alchemy Crafting Bench, which allows you to transform 3 5* artefact into a box that contain a random 5* artefact from 1 of 4 series of your choice: Bloodstained Chivalry, Gladiator's finale, Noblesse Oblige or Wanderer's Troupe.

https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Mystic_Offering

Comment: Just wanting to add that unless you are completely sure that you don't need any artifact from these four set, this is probably the only logic option. Basically, three trash artifacts are giving you a "free run" of a domain. This means that those three trash artifacts are *virtually* giving you the equivalent of 20 resin point. You could extend this to claim that leveling up artifact using 5* trash is basically like using resin to level up...

Comment: Now it's also possible to autoselect ("auto add" ingame) 1, 2 and 3 star artifacts to destroy. Must be by version 3.4 or 3.5. <3